# How do I assign a split list into different variable names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    listA = [11, 18, 19, 21, 29, 46]
    length = len(listA)

    splits = np.array_split(listA, length)
    i = 0
    for array in splits:
        print("test" + str([i]))
        print(list(array))
        i += 1
```

```
Output: 
test[0]
[11]
test[1]
[18]
test[2]
[19]
test[3]
[21]
test[4]
[29]
test[5]
[46]
```

What I am trying to accomplish here in this example is instead of printing out test[0] through test[5] and the items below (each in a new list), I want to do an assignment to a variable. To clarify what I mean I would basically like to name each list test[0] through 5 as variables so that I could work with them in my code later on.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you mean to say you want to create a column vector?

Comment: `a, b, c, d, e, f = splits`?

Comment: You may not need to assign splits to individual dynamic variables. You can just iterate through the splits "later" on and their variable would be `array` if you do this: `for array in splits:   \n    # the code you want to do later`

Comment: This technique is called "unpacking a list" https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences and https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpack-list/

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to make a dictionary?

- If you're looking to make the actual variables `test0` `test1` `test2` etc... that's a TERRIBLE idea unless done explicitly like in Paul M.'s comment: `a, b, c, d, e, f = splits`

Given:

```
listA = [11, 18, 19, 21, 29, 46]
```

Doing:

```
dictA = {f'test{i}':v for i, v in enumerate(listA)}

print(dictA)
print(dictA['test4'])
```

Output:

```
{'test0': 11, 'test1': 18, 'test2': 19, 'test3': 21, 'test4': 29, 'test5': 46}
29
```